# Remote job. Why don't want to work with freelancer?

Tags: remote, freelance

> Hi [my name]
> You don't need to relocate to [client's contry] for the
> position. However we can't pay your company but would do the
> employment through an EOR service. If still interested please make your
> application on our website Regards

So, why would anyone want employment / international employment instead of a Freelancer contract 5x8 hour week? ( full time)

- The client is in EU, myself too, but not in the same country.
- The job is advertised as a remote job.
- I have my own company (LLC), I can emit international invoices for my work, not need employment, just a company to company contract.

Comment: It might be because many still live 100 years ago where they belive if somebody gets hired, they have them for the rest of their life, but if they use them as a freelancer, they will be gone within 6 month.

Comment: @MrZach I met a local company in this days and they has exactly this vision. And uk UK it says "permanent" job, omg, permanent until? 20 day leave ? or until die? :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many people who want employment with the flexibility of remote work. These people do not want the overhead of invoicing, getting payments, government forms, insurance, and other aspects of being a freelancer. They would rather that someone else do that.

But you asked the question why would anyone want to be an employee. The real question needs to be why a company would force everyone to be an employee of an EOR. Many companies do not want the extra headaches of dealing with contractors and freelancers who own their own companies. If they can push those issues off to an EOR, then they can operate as if these contractors are their own employees but not deal with the HR issues.

There can be specific tax and governance issues in that country. For example, in the past in the US, a number of companies had hired contractors and operated like those contractors were employees. The government came back and redefined those contractors as employees and fined the companies for not having paid the proper taxes on those employees. That convinced the companies that when dealing with contractors, those contractors had to be employees of a contracting company and not freelancers. That way, the employment taxes would be properly paid.

Comment: Yes, Contractors, as a self employment, which legally aren't companies (LLC) they can be re-evaluated as employees in some cases. There are couple of points to check: fixed hours, assests given, paid hollidays and so on. As LLC is different: no paid hollyiday, no assets, you do your daily work and chard if you wrked, with your own assets. But you have an oppinion, upvoted

Answer (score 2):

bureaucracy and taxes

when the company uses an EOR service, they just need to register the employee there with the correct salary and approve the bills every month.

when contracting, that varies wildly, you are viewed as a service and not as an employee, which means they need a process to pay you every month

usually, companies either benefit from hiring people as employees because they can't wiggle out of worker laws and taxes, in countries where labor law is strong or employment taxes are high, hiring people as companies is frowned upon, or even plain illegal, because it's viewed as a way of defrauding the government of taxes.

so, that's why they don't want to work with you as a contractor, they either don't want to infringe any labor laws or they just don't want to create a whole new process for paying you.

I don't know how that works for EU, but I'm in south America, working for a US company. I'm in their EOR, I get paid in an international account and in my country I emit an international invoice and pay my taxes.

You could probably do the same, just check with an accountant.

Comment: thsanks man, it can be an idea, upvoted!